# What does FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage Method exactly do?

Tags: forms-authentication

I'm trying to implement a custom form-based authentication in SharePoint 2013. i come across this method:

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage Method (String, Boolean)
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka5ffkce(v=vs.110).aspx

i would like to know how does this method know if a user is already authenticated based on the string of the user name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage` does not know whether user is   authenticated based on credential or not. Basically, you have to check it before redirecting.

```
if (Membership.ValidateUser(UsernameTextbox.Text, PasswordTextbox.Text))
      FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(UsernameTextbox.Text, NotPublicCheckBox.Checked);
```

If you try to redirect without `Membership.ValidateUser`, you must get error.